# Save the data modified inside spark rdd.foreachPatition

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, rdd

I had a requirement where i performed operation inside `rdd.foreachPartition` of Spark RDD. Now i want to save the new data which was generated inside `foreachPartition` loop. But i believe save option is only available with RDD (or Dataframe). Is there a way i can save new data which was generated inside `foreachPartition` loop. My code looks as folows:

```
lines.foreachRDD{
rdd =>

val newRDD => rdd.map(...)

newRDD.foreachParition(iter =>
val newValues = iter.map(...)

//I want to save newValues 
)

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use `mapPartitions` and save later:

```
newRDD.mapParitions(iter =>
  iter.map(...)
).saveAsTextFile(...)
```